# Show Up/Downvotes on Community Wiki Answers in the /recent feed

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

I use the /users/recent page about 500 times per day to see if there are any new answers or votes, but this page does not show Up/Downvotes on community wiki questions/answers.

Granted, those are not affecting my reputation score, but I would still like to see changes, as I'm still interested to look at stuff that gets downvoted to understand why.

Comment: Something to note: you still get notified of upvotes after hitting the repcap, even though you get no rep from those. So the argument "you don't need to see them because they don't affect your rep" wouldn't even be consistent with how the site works now.

Answer (score 3):

This has been an annoyance for me as well. The only way to see it is to click on one of links like "Today" and see the full activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is annoying when I get "Nice answer" badge, so I click recent activity to see what has received a vote today, and I can't figure out what I got the badge for (because it looks like I haven't gotten any votes). So I have to go over to my profile and scroll though the list of questions sorted by rep to see the ones which are at 10 votes.